# local server for TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

I have installed Visual Studio Ultimate in my system. I wanted to configure TFS in my system as the feature is given. So how do I configure my TFS server without using any other system? I wish to add some of my hard disk space as server for TFS, is it possible? Can I use localhost (IIS) as server for TFS? Well I tried for localhost, but its giving error as URL or server name is invalid. I have started using TFS few weeks back in office, and have used any source control software before this in home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I came to know whats wrong. So decided to post the solution behind my confusion. I have Visual Studio Ultimate software and it do not have TFS in it. And MSDN license for Ultimate suite has has everything in it. So there is a difference between `Visual Studio Ultimate` and `Visual Studio Ultimate Suite` which I really failed to observe.

I know it was a basic thing but still decided to post the solution so if anyone is confused regarding this, can get some help. Damn, I wasted my money.

Answer (score 5):

First you will need to install Team Foundation Server. Installing Visual Studio Ultimate does not install Team Foundation Server itself, but Visual Studio Ultimate bundle should have Team Foundation Server SKU.

Following this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee259682.aspx) to find out what you need to install TFS. It has details about prereqs, installation steps, and different configurations of TFS you can choose.

For your setup, looks like you want a single-server configuration with SQL Express (installed as part of TFS) and IIS. The installation and configuration wizard would either install the required components for you or fail the readiness checks to let you know which components you are missing.

Answer (score 1):

try your machine name.

my machine name is mikev-ws and my tfs url is...

Browse here - http://mikev-ws:8080/tfs/

OR

Open `Team Foundation Administration Console` to see all the locations.

Comment: Unable to connect to TFS........Technical error: Unable to connect to Remote server

Comment: Wish I could help. Sounds like you need to ask a new question.

Comment: Yep, not a problem. TFS2010 with Sql Dev Ed, VS2010 Ultimate on Win7x64.